# Match gradients of two divs, if those have different width

Tags: html, css, gradient, repeating-linear-gradient

I have 10 inline divs, which have same gradient type - 45deg lines, but gradients have different colors and divs have different width.

Is it possible to match gradient? (hope pics below explain it)

My CSS for gradient. Only color changes.

```css
   #div1 {
     background: repeating-linear-gradient(
        45deg,
        rgba(155,155,155,0.8),
        rgba(155,155,155,0.8) 3px,
        rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 3px,
        rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 6px);
    }

    #div2 {
     background: repeating-linear-gradient(
        45deg,
        rgba(235,102,107,0.6),
        rgba(235,102,107,0.6) 3px,
        rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 3px,
        rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 6px);
    }
div {
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" style="width: 30px"></div><div id="div2" style="width: 40px"></div>
```

How it looks like now (lines are not matching):

[image: lines are not matching]

How I want it to look like:

[image: lines are matching]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use both gradients on the same element and use `background-clip` trick to hide a part of the first one that will not go until the padding where you will see the second one:

```css
.box {
  height:100px;
  width:80px;
  padding-right:50px;
  margin:5px;
  display:inline-block;
 background: 
 repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    rgba(235,102,107,0.6),
    rgba(235,102,107,0.6) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 6px) content-box,
 linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) content-box, /*avoid the overlap of both gradient*/
 repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    rgba(155,155,155,0.8),
    rgba(155,155,155,0.8) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 6px) padding-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="width:100px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="padding-right:100px;"></div>
```

If you have more than 2 gradients you can consider `background-size`. The trick it to have a white background layer under each one to hide the pervious gradient:

```css
.box {
  height:100px;
  width:300px;
  margin:5px;
  display:inline-block;
 background: 
 /*First gradient*/
 repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    rgba(235,102,107,0.6),
    rgba(235,102,107,0.6) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 6px) left/30% 100%,
 linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) left/30% 100%,
 /*Second one*/
 repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    rgba(155,155,155,0.8),
    rgba(155,155,155,0.8) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 6px) left/60% 100%,
 linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) left/60% 100%,
 /**/
 repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    rgba(15,15,15,0.8),
    rgba(15,15,15,0.8) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 6px) left/80% 100%,
 linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) left/80% 100%,
 /**/
 repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    rgba(12,155,155,0.8),
    rgba(12,155,155,0.8) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 6px) left/100% 100%,
 linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) left/100% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Here is another idea that rely on `mix-blend-mode` to achieve the same result with less of code:

```css
.box {
  height:100px;
  width:300px;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  background: 
  repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    rgba(0,0,0,0.6),
    rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 6px),
    #fff;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,blue 20%,red 20%, red 40%,orange 40%);
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Here is another idea that rely on `background-attachment:fixed` where you can keep transparency also:

```css
.box {
  height:100px;
  width:30px;
  margin:5px 0;
  display:inline-block;
 background-attachment:fixed;
}
#f1 {
 background-image:repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    rgba(155,155,155,0.8),
    rgba(155,155,155,0.8) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 6px);
}
#f2 {
 background-image:repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    rgba(15,15,15,0.8),
    rgba(15,15,15,0.8) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 6px);
}
#f3 {
 background-image:repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    rgba(12,155,155,0.8),
    rgba(12,155,155,0.8) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 6px);
 }
```

```html
<div class="box" id="f1"></div><div class="box" id="f2" style="width:100px"></div><div class="box" id="f3" style="width:150px"></div>
```

Another way with multiple background:

```css
.box {
  height:100px;
  width:300px;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  background: 
  repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    transparent,
    transparent 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,1) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,1) 6px),
   linear-gradient(to right,
    rgba(235,102,107,0.6) 20%,
    rgba(155,155,155,0.8) 20%, rgba(155,155,155,0.8) 40%,
    rgba(15,15,15,0.8) 40%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for such detailed answer with examples! I picked background-attachment:fixed which works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got this one:

```
<div id="div1" style="width: 100px; height: 50px;"></div>
```

```css
#div1 {
 background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    rgba(155,155,155,0.8),
    rgba(155,155,155,0.8) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 6px);
}

#div2 {
 background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    rgba(235,102,107,0.6),
    rgba(235,102,107,0.6) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 6px);
        background-position: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" style="width: 100px; height: 50px;"></div>
<div id="div2" style="width: 100px; height: 50px;"></div>
```

I think background-position is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't work for me as I have different width of divs. I tested with another example - and should go for background-position: -6px. But definitely something to play with. +1

Answer (score 1):

I think this would do the trick: make your divs solid and lay a striped div on top of it. (inspired by Byoung730)

```css
div {height: 100px; display: inline-block;}

#div1 {
 background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    rgba(155,155,155,0.8),
    rgba(155,155,155,0.8) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 6px);
}

#div2 {
 background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    rgba(235,102,107,0.6),
    rgba(235,102,107,0.6) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 3px,
    rgba(250,250,250,0.4) 6px);
}

#div3 {
 background:rgba(155,155,155,0.8)}
 
#div4 {
 background:rgba(235,102,107,0.6)}
 
#div5 {
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  width: 500px;
 background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    rgba(255,255,255,1),
    rgba(255,255,255,1) 3px,
    rgba(255,255,255,0) 3px,
    rgba(255,255,255,0) 6px);}
```

```html
your example:<br>
<div id="div1" style="width: 100px"></div><div id="div2" style="width: 400px"></div>

smooth one:<br>
<div id="div3" style="width: 100px"></div><div id="div4" style="width: 400px"></div><div id="div5"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make it one row div, and use something like:

```
    .book {
      background-image: linear-gradient(105deg,
      rgba($color-white, .9) 0%,
      rgba($color-white, .9) 50%,
      transparent 50%),
      url(../img/nat-10.jpg);
```

The percentages, if equal, cause an immediate color change, rather than a gradual one.  So this goes right from my white color to transparent.  So, using one div will keep the lines straight, and the percentages will change the colors.  I had a slant on mine, so you'll want to change the initial angle.

HTML:

```
    <section class="section-book" id="book">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="book">
          <div class="book__form">
            <form action="#" class="form">
```

Comment: Could you kindly add html? Does this work if divs have different gradient color?